# Can I filter a Stream<T> by element's class an get a Stream<U> in one step?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Lets say I have

```
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
```

And I have a list of Animals
Using Guava FluentIterable I can filter and convert in one step

```
List<Cat> cats = FluentIterable.from(animals)
    .filter(Cat.class)
    .toList();
```

Using Java8 I need to do

```
List<Cat> cats = animals.stream()
     .filter(c -> c instanceof Cat)
     .map(c -> (Cat) c)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There is no way I can make the filter & map in one step, right?

Comment: In C# it's the `Enumerable.OfType<T>` extension method, but I don't know what it is in java.

Comment: the magical `flatMap()` .... but don't do it :)

Comment: also try `.filter(Cat.class::isInstance).map(Cat.class::cast)` - it's not any better of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` step is unnecessary at runtime (it simply does nothing), you need it just to bypass the type checking during the compilation. Alternatively you can use dirty unchecked cast:

```
List<Cat> cats = ((Stream<Cat>) (Stream<?>) animals.stream().filter(
        c -> c instanceof Cat)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Unfortunately there's no standard way to do this in single step, but you may use third-party libraries. For example, in my [`StreamEx`](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library there's a `select` method which [solves this problem](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/7b998cb25122219cacd0bd762faa991ff61da7cd/src/main/java/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.java#L158):

```
List<Cat> cats = StreamEx.of(animals).select(Cat.class).toList();
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was a compilation-only thing...